# Get Form Array and Send to email

Tags: php, arrays, forms

So I'm still learning PHP, and I've got a form that has 4 arrays.  I'm trying to get the arrays sent to my email along with some other information.  The email I keep getting says "array, array"  (then the rest of the information shows up correctly).  I can't figure out what I'm missing.

I can get the parent info to show up correctly, but I'm stuck on getting the Child Information to translate over to email.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Parent Info
    $pFname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pFname']);
    $pLname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pLname']);
    $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pEmail']);
    $street = mysql_escape_string($_POST['street']);
    $city = mysql_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $state = mysql_escape_string($_POST['state']);
    $zip = mysql_escape_string($_POST['zip']);

    // Child Info
    $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
    $birthday = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Birthday']);
    $gender = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Gender']);
    $rel = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Rel']);

    $msg1 = "From: " . ' ' . $pFname . ' ' . $pLname  . ' ' . ' ' . $pEmail 
    . ' ' . ' ';

    foreach ($_POST['Name'] as $names){
        $name = $names;
    }

    foreach ($_POST['Birthday'] as $birthdays){
        $birthday = $birthdays;
    }

    foreach ($_POST['Gender'] as $genders){
        $gender = $genders;
    }

    foreach ($_POST['Rel'] as $rels) {
        $rel = $rels;
    }

    $msg = "Name: " . " " . $name . " - " . $gender .  "Birthday: " . 
     $birthday . " " . "Relationship: " . $rel . "\n\r";

    $to = 'joe@joe.com;
    $subject = 'Birthday Club Application';
    $msg = $msg . "\r\n";
    $msg .= "First Name: " . $pFname . "\r\n";
    $msg .= "Last Name: " . $pLname . "\r\n";
    $msg .= "Email: " . $email . "\r\n";
    $msg .= "Street: " . $street . "\r\n";
    $msg .= "City: " . $city . "\r\n";
    $msg .= "State: " . $state . "\r\n";
    $msg .= "Zip: " . $zip . "\r\n";

    $headers = 'From: ' . $pEmail . "\r\n";
    $headers1 = 'From: mycompany.com';
    /*$goto_after_mail = "birthdayClub.php";*/

    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $msg1, $headers);

    header("Location: " . $goto_after_mail);
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<form id="parent-info" method="post" action="<?php echo 
 htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "])?>">

    <h1>Guardian Information</h1>
    <h4>*All fields required*</h4>

    <input type="text" name="pFname" class="parent-entry" placeholder="First Name:" >

    <input type="text" name="pLname" class="parent-entry" placeholder="Last Name:" >

    <input type="text" name="pEmail" class="parent-entry" placeholder="Email:" >

    <input type="text" name="street" class="parent-entry" placeholder="Street Address:" >

    <input type="text" name="city" class="parent-entry" placeholder="City:" >

    <input type="text" name="state" class="parent-entry" placeholder="State:" >

    <input type="text" name="zip" class="parent-entry" placeholder="Zip Code:" >
    <br>

    <h2>Child Information</h2>
    <h4>*All fields required*</h4>

    <div class="child-form">

        <input type="text" name="Name[]" placeholder="Childs Name:" class="parent-entry" value " "; >

        <input type="text" name="Gender[]" placeholder="Gender:" class="parent-entry" value " ";>

        <input type="text" name="Birthday[]" placeholder="Ex: 1/1/01:" class="parent-entry" value " "; >

        <input type="text" name="Rel[]" placeholder="Relation to child:" class="parent-entry" value " ";>

    </div>
```

Comment: You should have a closing apostrophe on the line that says `$to = 'joe@joe.com;`

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` __escapes a string__ `$_POST['Name']` is __not a string__ I don't even know why you use this function.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing @u_mulder

Comment: You have a syntax error here `$to = 'joe@joe.com;`, forgot the ending singlequote.

Comment: PHP's string representation of any array is the string `Array`, regardless of what's in the array. So any time you see that when you're expecting to see some different text, it means that you've tried to print out an array that you thought was a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($_POST['Name'] as $names)
```

This line suggests that `$_POST['Name']` is an array. If that's the case you will have problems with this line:

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
```

That function expects a string. When you feed it an array, it will convert it to the string "*Array*". The same applies to all the child arrays.  You're using `mysql_escape_string` on arrays.

What you want to do instead, since you seem to have an array of children, is to loop through that array and pick up each child's info to add to the email.

Another alternative, if you don't want to loop through all those arrays, is to use the `print_r` function with its second optional parameter set to `true`.  This will transform the array into a user-readable string.

Change

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
```

To:

```
$name = print_r($_POST['Name'], true);
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6e9becc0f16c61902c2a8010552c5f183beb4b0)

Comment: Ok, so I removed the mysql_escape_string from the $_POST variables.  The syntax error was just an error copying over to here.  I want to loop through each childs info and add to the email, but thats where I'm sort of stuck.  Im about 99% sure I can use a foreach loop, but as I said, Im still learning PHP and the foreach loop is giving me fits right now.

Comment: @OrangeFreak that along still doesn't get to the root of your problem. You're trying to include an array within a string when you do `"Name: " . $name`.  It will only print "Array".  I gave you two approaches you could use to get the values inside the array as a string.

Comment: I made the suggested correct to the variables.  Its still sending me 'Array'.